# Downloading File with JavaScript Cookie in Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, download

Using the browser if I visit a certain direct download `URL`, it automatically downloads the file. However, when I use `Java` code to download the file, I get the `HTML` code instead of the file contents:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js"></script>
<script>function toNumbers(d) {
    var e = [];
    d.replace(/(..)/g, function (d) {
        e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
    });
    return e
}

function toHex() {
    for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f < d.length; f++) e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
    return e.toLowerCase()
}

var a = toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"), b = toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),
    c = toNumbers("b5eb8dc5c53e5107faa7ec1c1f3e3dc7");
document.cookie = "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
location.href = "http://example.com/Test.txt?i=1";</script>
<noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with
    Javascript support
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

My file downloading code is e.g. the following:

```
URL url = new URL("...");
try (InputStream inputStream = url.openStream())
{
    Files.copy(inputStream, downloadedFilePath, REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

How would it be possible to download the file programmatically in `Java`? [There are ways to execute `JavaScript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856279/call-external-javascript-functions-from-java-code) but how is it supposed to work exactly? It seems like the `document.cookie` has to be set (correctly) to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading works by passing the correct cookie value alongside of the request. The cookie value can be retrieved using e.g. the [`Google Chrome`](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome) `DevTools` -> `Application` -> `Cookies`. Since in my example the cookie value does not change, a code like the following would do the trick:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class DownloadWithCookieExample
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("...");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "blabla"); // Hard-coded correct cookie value
            String readStream = readStream(con.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(readStream);
        } catch (Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String readStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                stringBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
    }
}
```

An even better solution would be to execute the `JavaScript` to receive the cookie value and to pass the result. This task is left as an exercise for another answer for whoever knows how to do this elegantly.