# Is there any way to execute javascript functions from java code

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am trying to execute a javascript function from java code.

I used JavascriptExecutor from selenium package.

I tried below code

```
  JavascriptExecutor js;
  js.executeScript("let time;");
  js.executeScript("time = 2;");
  js.executeScript("function f(){console.log(time);}");
  js.executeScript("f()");
```

This is output

```
Exception in thread "Thread 0" 
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: f is not defined
```

Is there any way to execute the above script from java code? is it possible?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856279/call-external-javascript-functions-from-java-code

Comment: @i.bondarenko Thanks. but I want to know if it's possible with JavaScriptExecutor method

Comment: Each time you call `executeScript` it creates a *separate* script. You must put all those lines into the same call, so they can see results of each other.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov but from the above snippet, 'time' variable is getting recognized even though they are separate scripts. Is there any explanation for that?

Comment: @SameerKhan, how do you know it's recognized, since you never print it? `myvariable = 1` is valid javascript on it's own, it means global variable assignment, and creates the variable it not present already, unless in strict mode (which you aren't).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String script = "let time;time = 2;function f(){console.log(time);}f()";
JavascriptExecutor js;
js.executeScript(script);
```

Comment: I have a use case where I have to use two different lines of executeScript. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You could try to inject your script into the DOM using document.write... "<script>your script</script>"  (I've never tried this myself.)   So your first call to execute script executes a script that injects a script.  Not sure why you wouldn't just put all of it in one string though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window properties (or any built-in really) which will stick around:

```
js.executeScript("window.time = 4");
js.executeScript("window.f = () => console.log(window.time)");
js.executeScript("window.f()");
```